# convert Decimal to signed 2's compliment and vice versa in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, numbers, frontend

i am stucked with 2's compliment about how its works. i am making a number converter same like https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html  i have added all the conversions except this 2's compliment. also this conversion is in all hexadecimal to decimal, decimal to binary conversion, decimal to hexadecimal conversions. i don't understand these conversions very well so a explaned answer is highly appericiated.

> below is the functions which i use in another js file, but this code missing 2's compliment. i have no idea on how do i calculate it. i want the same functionality like this https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html

```
// =============== Number Converter ===============
// program to convert from any type(decimal,binary or hexadecimal) to any type(binary, decimal or hexadecimal)

export function convertToDecimal(binary) {
    //  use it like this
    // it will return decimal value of binary number
    // convertToDecimal('101') ==> 5
    
    return parseInt(binary, 2);
}


export function convertToBinary(decimal) {
    /* use it like this
    it will return binary value of decimal number
    convertToBinary(5) ==> '101'
    */
    return decimal.toString(2);
}



export function binary2Decimal(binary) {
    /* use it like this
    it will return decimal value of binary number
    binary2Decimal('101') ==> 5
    */
    return parseInt(binary, 2);
}

export function binary2Octal(binary) {
    /* use it like this
    it will return octal value of binary number
    binary2Octal('101') ==> '5'
    */
    return parseInt(binary, 2).toString(8);
}

export function binary2hex(binary) {
    /* use it like this
    it will return hexa value of binary number
    binary2hex('101') ==> '5'
    */
    return parseInt(binary, 2).toString(16);
}


export function fromBinary2Hex(binary) {
    let resp = new Object();
    resp.hex = binary2hex(binary);
    resp.decimal = binary2Decimal(binary);
    return resp;
}

export function hex2Binary(hex) {
    return parseInt(hex, 16).toString(2);
}

export function hex2Decimal(hex) {
    return parseInt(hex, 16);
}

export function fromHex(hex) {
    let resp = new Object();
    resp.binary = hex2Binary(hex);
    resp.decimal = hex2Decimal(hex);
    return resp;
}

export function decimal2Binary(decimal) {
    return parseInt(decimal).toString(2);
}

export function decimal2hex(decimal) {
    return parseInt(decimal).toString(16);
}

export function fromDecimal(decimal) {
    let resp = new Object();
    resp.binary = decimal2Binary(decimal);
    resp.hex = decimal2hex(decimal);
    return resp;
}
```

Comment: Please note that SO is not a tutorial or code-writing service; can you [edit] to clarify your specific question?

Comment: can you please add code for what you have tried so far?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  i have update the question with code. it's a js file from where i import code from and use it another js file where i am also doing some DOM manipulation.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera please check the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out may it will help you.

```js
(function(){

    var ConvertBase = function (num) {
        return {
            from : function (baseFrom) {
                return {
                    to : function (baseTo) {
                        return parseInt(num, baseFrom).toString(baseTo);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    };
        
    // binary to decimal
    ConvertBase.bin2dec = function (num) {
        return ConvertBase(num).from(2).to(10);
    };
    
    // binary to hexadecimal
    ConvertBase.bin2hex = function (num) {
        return ConvertBase(num).from(2).to(16);
    };
    
    // decimal to binary
    ConvertBase.dec2bin = function (num) {
        return ConvertBase(num).from(10).to(2);
    };
    
    // decimal to hexadecimal
    ConvertBase.dec2hex = function (num) {
        return ConvertBase(num).from(10).to(16);
    };
    
    // hexadecimal to binary
    ConvertBase.hex2bin = function (num) {
        return ConvertBase(num).from(16).to(2);
    };
    
    // hexadecimal to decimal
    ConvertBase.hex2dec = function (num) {
        return ConvertBase(num).from(16).to(10);
    };
    
    this.ConvertBase = ConvertBase;
    
})(this);
console.log(ConvertBase.bin2dec('101'));
console.log(ConvertBase.dec2bin('5'));
console.log(ConvertBase.dec2hex('5'));
console.log(ConvertBase.hex2bin('5'));
```